# How to left align NSString with arabic string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using NSString to print sting in the following format

**Product name.    Price**

Expected Output:

[image: I want this out put]

Current output :

[image: I am getting this out put]

My code is

```
tmp_STR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%19s (%@)%@\r\n",[prod_price cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],prod_QTY,prod_NAME];
```

Product name will be either in Arabic or in English. But I want to print the string as per the screen shot attached

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using two strings. One for the name and one for the price. Then using `NSTextAlignment` property of UILabel or whatever you use to display it.

Comment: You can use NSAttributedString, but since it about "rendering", you may want to look more on the UI part, like UILabel. But 2 UILabel could be interesting too.

Comment: You can add manual space into the string to achieve this, when you are printing just do this `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%19s (%@)   %@\r\n",[prod_price cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],prod_QTY,prod_NAME];`

Comment: @iphonic am doing the same

Comment: @iphonic It is working fine with English text for Arabic its not working

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use two different labels, one for left aligned text and another for right aligned text.

Also, set content compression priority for one of both label, according to your requirement for data visiblity when there is long texts in first (lef) label.

Comment: I am not able to use label I want to print the string in POS printer